# Weird behavior of for loop with multiple sprites in Sprite Kit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop, ios7, sprite-kit

I am spawning 12 sprites to place in a game.  Each sprite needs to have an original name.  I am doing this by using a for loop.  I have split the loop up to show you what is happening.  So for the first couple of charges:

```
for (int i = -4; i <= 0; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"i = %i", i);
        [self spawnChargesWithNumber:i];
    }
```

The NSLog tells me that i is -4, -3, -2, -1, 0.  As it should.  This calls the method `spawnChargesWithNumber:i` which looks like this:

```
- (void)spawnChargesWithNumber:(int)number
{
NSLog(@"number is %i", number);

_chargedBall = [[ChargedBall alloc] initWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ChargedBall%i", number]];

//code to make a random position

_chargedBall.position = CGPointMake(actualX, random);
_chargedBall.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chargeNumber%i", number];
_chargedBall.zPosition = 15;
_chargedBall.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:13.0f];
_chargedBall.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
_chargedBall.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
_chargedBall.physicsBody.mass = 0.1;
_chargedBall.velocity = CGPointMake(actualVelocityX, 0.0);
_chargedBall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = chargeCategory;
_chargedBall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory;
_chargedBall.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = playerCategory | selfCategory;
[self.map addChild:_chargedBall];

NSLog(@"You made charge with name %@", _chargedBall.name);

if (!_enemies) {
    _enemies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

[_enemies addObject:_chargedBall];
NSLog(@"you added %@ to the array", _chargedBall.name);
}
```

I have an object called `ChargedBall`. The `NSLog` first tells me the number, which corresponds to `i` from above.  Then it tells me I made charge (chargeNumberi) where it follows the same pattern.  Then I add that `chargedBall` to an array.  During the game if I collide with any of these, my `NSLog` from `didBeginContact` method tells me that I have contacted the proper charge.  All is working as planned.

Since I actually have 12 charges and not 5 I have another `for` loop to show you.  It is basically the same taking off where the other ended:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"i = %i", i);
        [self spawnChargesWithNumber:i];
    }
```

I did originally have these together, but I wanted to show you what was happening.  After the call to `spawnChargesWithNumber:i` I get the rest of the charges.  However, they are reversed!  I don't get it.  The `NSLog` still tells me the `i`, number, you created `chargeNumberi`, and added it to the array.  I even `NSLog` the name of the image and it still corresponds.  But `chargeNumber7` shows picture 1, `chargeNumber6`shows picture 2, `chargeNumber 5` shows picture 3, four is fine because there is an odd number of sprites to make, `chargeNumber3` show picture 5, `chargeNumber2` shows picture6 and `chargeNumber 7` shows picture 1.  So the entire thing is flipped.  I have checked the pictures and they are all correct.  This even happened when I had the `for` loop as just one loop, the positive charges were switched, but not zero to negative 4.  Does anyone know why this would happen?  I `NSLog` everything I could think of, I even changed the picture names, but nothing worked.  If you need some more code from other places I can post, I am just so confused right now!

Comment: So what are you image files actually called on disk? I have never tried using negative frame numbers but I would consider it bad practice, your image files should be numbered "file_0001@2x.png", "file_0002@2x.png", "file_0003@2x.png" etc. (obviously file can be anything, and _0001 is just personal choice but the actual file numbers should start at 0000 or 0001 and go up from there. Also note that in many 3D packages frame 0 does not have motion blur so its usual to skip frame 0000 and start frame sequences at 0001.

Comment: @fuzzygoat, the files are named chargeNumber(insert variable here). The variable goes from -4 to 7. This has worked out fine with the negatives though. Don't know what you mean with the frames. These are all individual sprites, not a sequence to show animation. There are 12 different sprites with 12 different unique names. Only the positive charges and their pictures are reversed. Although NSLog says they are correct.

Comment: If you assign the images manually (without the loop) does it give the correct result i.e. SKSpriteNode *charge1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteWithImageNamed:@"chargeNumber1"]; Also I would suggest having an extension on the images files i.e. chargeNumber1.png (if you don't already) also I would possibly rethink your numbering convention as using "-" for variable/file names (particularly in programming) is considered bad practice, that is unless you are actually wanting to do a subtraction. I don't think thats your problem as you are doing this is a string but its worth keeping in mind for the future.

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger ? You can step through this code and verify everything is as you 'expect' it to be.

Comment: @prototypical, I used some stops and NSLogs, but any tips?  Like how I can see what my variables are?  Thanks.

Comment: @fuzzygoat, I tried hard coding the sprites. Even when I used the image name as "CharedBall7.png", it loaded ChargedBall1.png. However, if I click on the actual png file, ChargedBall7.png shows the correct image.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DebugYourApp/DebugYourApp.html

Comment: Your question is not the type of question that should be on this site, as it amounts to "can you help me debug my code?". I see chunks of your code, so I can't know one way or the other if something relevant is missing.

Comment: I will say this however... I have had situations before where a some weird caching issues occurred with images. Let me ask you, have you renamed any of these images after you imported them into xcode ? If so, did you rename them in Finder or in Xcode ? Have you tried removing the images from your project and then adding them back ?

Comment: If you believe it's a cache issue, you can delete derived data for your app, reset content and settings for the simulator, close XCode and the simulator and restart them. Also do a product/clean and recompile.

Comment: @prototypical, sorry you think this shouldn't be on the site. I felt as though I had programmed my for loop incorrectly and that someone on SO would be able to see it.  I ran the debugger as the Apple docs said that you linked me too.  The images all came up as they should.  So I deleted my derived data and now it works. I though cleaning did the same thing as I had cleaned several times. Because I had renamed them.

Comment: Well, glad it is fixed for you. It's not that I don't want to help you, but this kind of question as it's written doesn't help others as it's so specific to your problem. The takeaway here is that if you suspect a caching issue kill the derived data etc. But that kind of information is available in other questions/answers where people took the time to drill down to the heart of the issue and therefore it's helpful to more people.

Comment: My point was that if you use the debugger and verify that everything is as you expect, then 99% of your question is irrelevant. If you hardcode a sprite with a filename and it comes up wrong, then it's time to think about a caching issue.

Comment: @prototypical, I am going to write this all up in an answer so others can see.  I really didn't think that it was a caching issue at all, but I will keep that in mind, because I really thought what I did was correct.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: For example the question could have been - "Creating a SKSpriteNode with hardcoded filename is loading wrong image." The explain how you look at the image with that filename in XCode and it doesn't match what you see when running the app. Pretty straightforward issue and I'd guess many would suggest a cache issue. But with all this code with -4 to 7 loops etc... Most will assume you just need to debug and maybe the decision to do that kind of loop and naming convention is indicative of other areas of your code.  But still glad you have it fixed, I know it sucks to be stuck.

Comment: No problem at all, glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved.  I really thought that I had programmed my for loop incorrectly. However, with the help of fuzzygoat and prototypical, I hardcoded everything, and used the debugger to find that all was as I intended.  Therefore, prototypical suggested cleaning the derived data, as I had changed the image names after they had been imported to Xcode.  I thought that cleaning the product did the same as deleting the derived data, but perhaps not. So thanks to everyone that looked and thanks to all that helped.  You filled my brain with knowledge once again!